# Multiple Access Keys for the Same User

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cli

I have discovered that there is a particular User that is enabled for programmatic access in my company's AWS account. I have been tasked with recreating an Access Key and Security Token for one of my colleagues, despite it already having one. I want to deactivate the original one. I feel that from a security standpoint, it is better to have only one Access Key/Token rather than multiples.

Can anyone tell me if this is a good choice to have? One of my colleagues has asked me why I would want to do that and when I told him my reasoning, I dont think he was a 100% convinced my reasoning was good. Can you please tell me if there are any advantages to having multiple access keys/secret keys to the same user? Because I can't think of any. Also, can you please provide any kind of supporting articles that would cover this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under [AWS IAM Access Keys best practices](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-access-keys-best-practices.html) I believe these sections apply:

- **Use different access keys for different applications.** Do this so that you can isolate the permissions and revoke the access keys for individual applications if an access key is exposed. Having separate access keys for different applications also generates distinct entries in AWS CloudTrail log files, which makes it easier for you to determine which application performed specific actions.
- **Rotate access keys periodically.** Change access keys on a regular basis. For details, see Rotating Access Keys (AWS CLI, Tools for Windows PowerShell, and AWS API) in the IAM User Guide and How to Rotate Access Keys for IAM Users on the AWS Security Blog.

The first item clearly gives a reason to use multiple access keys with a single IAM account. I think using multiple keys would also make the second item, key rotation easier. You could create a second access key set, switch your applications over, verify that the previous set is no longer being used to access the AWS API, and then delete the old set.

Comment: Thanks for that information. I must have overlooked that first reason because I did read that article but thought it applied for different IAM users (not the same) so that actually makes a lot of sense. As far as the old key, i did deactivate it but not delete it.

Comment: Actually, the first item recommends using multiple access keys, not overloading multiple access keys within a single IAM user. And "isolate the permissions" solidifies that because you cannot give different permissions to each access key under the same IAM user. You can satisfy item 1 by using distinct IAM users.

Comment: I disagree on how you are interpreting the first point, but I also agree that it's probably a little easier to track by separate users than multiple keys on a single user.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have docs for recommending a single access key per user, but AWS does recommend rotating access keys regularly. See [Managing Access Keys for IAM Users](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_access-keys.html), the section titled "Rotating Access Keys".

So you should, as best practice, do the following on a regular schedule (every 30, 60, 90 days, etc.)

1. Create a second access key for your user
2. Wherever you are using the first access key, replace it with the second
3. Wait a short time, and confirm the first access key is not being used.
4. After confirmation, disable or delete the first access key

The two access key system is to allow for this rotation to occur while keeping the time where an access key is disabled/deleted, but still being used to a minimum. I've been bit in other tools where you have to disable the old key when you generate a new key. Because sometimes it takes time to put the new keys in use after they're generated.

If a user needs more than one access key, then there should be a question why one needs to be, rather than multiple. There are benefits to using multiple users:

1. The permissions can be more granular
2. If a key gets leaked, there are fewer places where it needs to be replaced
3. You have a better audit trail of what tools are acting on your account, and when

For these reason, I recommend only having one access key "in the field".

I think, really, if someone wants to actually use 2 keys for a single user, they're just being lazy.

I create individual IAM users and roles for every tool that needs access. I never reuse them.

**Update**

AWS recommends rotating access keys on a regular schedule.

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-access-keys-best-practices.html

Further, their "howto" on the key rotation process uses both allocated access keys on an IAM user:

Source: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-rotate-access-keys-for-iam-users/

Ergo, target for one access key "in use" per IAM user at any given time.

Comment: Each key shows up distinctly in CloudTrail so I think that negates your second point about multiple users being better than multiple keys.

Comment: True, but the access keys only show up in the JSON, and not in the AWS console GUI. The console allows searching by user name, but not access key. And the IAM "Access Advisor" is granular to the user, not to the access key. And by putting both access keys in use, you cannot have "deployment overlap" while rotating keys.